# Mediawiki: Display the pagename of the 2nd page in a 3-level(nested) transclusion

Tags: templates, mediawiki, transclusion

## Desire

Within Mediawiki, on the 'top-level' page, I want to show the 2nd-level's 'page-name' in a 3-level page transclusion(nested pages).

## Example Description

In this example, I have 3 pages. '3', '2', 'template:1'

- page '3' transcludes '2', `{{:2}}`
- page '2' transcludes 'template:1', `{{1}}`
- page 'template:1' includes a call for the 'page-name', `{{PAGENAME}}`

I wish for page '3' to display '2' ie the pagename of page '2'. So the output of '3' would be
`2`

## The simplest real-life example:

Pages:

- https://happytrees.org/dieshots/3 transcludes page '2', `{{:2}}`
- https://happytrees.org/dieshots/2 transcludes page 'template:1', `{{1}}`
- https://happytrees.org/dieshots/template:1 contains the code for `{{PAGENAME}}`

Desired result:

- page '3' displays the number `2`

Actual result:

- page '3' displays the number `3`

## Things I have tried

here is a mess of things i have tried
[mess of attempts](https://happytrees.org/sites/dieshots-mediawiki-1.35.4/index.php?title=Template:A&action=edit)

## Ultimate goal

Ultimately I want to want to have an edit link on each dieshot box. For example [page with multiple dieshots](https://happytrees.org/dieshots/Angstrem_-_Z80_family) will have an 'edit link' on each dieshot box which will goto the [dieshot's edit page](https://happytrees.org/sites/dieshots-mediawiki-1.35.4/index.php?title=Angstrem_-_KR1858VM1&action=edit).  The 'dieshot's page' uses the template [dieshot box template](https://happytrees.org/dieshots/Template:Dieshot-box). The 'template' contains the 'edit page code'. and the edit link ultimatly goes to 'dieshot's edit page'

## Software

if it maters

- MediaWiki     1.35.3
- Extension:ParserFunctions 1.6.0
- Extension:Variables   2.5.1

Thanks
Zef the Tinker

Comment: Put `{{subst:PAGENAME}}` on the page '2'.

Comment: cant, I need the code for 'PAGNAME variable' in 'Template:1', and set on on page '2'. page 2 can only transclude instance of 'template:1'.  Well....... maybe i can but its not ideal. On my 'preload page' for page '2' it would have to include {{subst:PAGENAME}} with a do not edit below this line warning. Also page '2' could never be renamed, necessary editing. Example: [tempate:1a](https://happytrees.org/dieshots/template:1a),  [2a](https://happytrees.org/dieshots/2a),  [3a](https://happytrees.org/dieshots/3a)